# How to change indent in notebook input cell without shifting the whole code to the right?

Tags: front-end, formatting

V 12.1 on windows.

This is easier shown in pictures. I like to have large indent for `If` and `Do` etc... to make it more clear. But the option [LineIndent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineIndent.html) increases the indent for the whole code to the right, and very little for the stuff I am interested in, which is `If`, `Do` etc...

The default `LineIndent` is `1`.   Here are 3 pictures showing what happens when changing this from 1 to 2 to 3. Notice how the whole code shifts to the right. I do not want this. I want only to change the indent of these constructs above, inside the code. But without that initial indent added.   Even though the indent for `If` has increased, but it has not increased by same proportion as the whole shift that happens.

[image]

So I really want is the following (which I did manually for illustration)

[image]

To get close to the above using `LineIndent` this is the result. You can see how much the whole code shifted to the right due to that initial indent, which I do not want

[image]

I played with some of the options in option inspector, but can't figure which will do what I want, if any

[image]

I know I can use code cell and do my own formatting, but code cells have its own issues as well.

Is there a setting that will change line indent, but without adding that initial indent? I do not like the whole code shifting so much to the right.

Here is the code used above

```
foo := Module[{x, y, m},
  x = 1;
  If[x == 1,
   Print["x=1"]
   ,
   Print["x is not 1"]
   ];

  Do[
   x = 1
   , {m, 1, 10}
   ];

  y
  ]
```

Comment: I believe your initial indent includes both the indent for `:=` as well as the indent for `Module`. I don't think there is a way to change this.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Code cell style rather than the Input cell style when I want complete control over indentation and formatting. On a Mac, it is Command-8 for Code and Command-9 for Input.

Comment: thanks, yes I know about code style, but it has its own issues. I wanted to use the standard input cell style, but only adjust the amount of indent as shown.